# MVC4 EF5 - Ajax call error after Linq SqlQuery()

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

My view looks like

```
<form onsubmit="return Filter();" class="my-form">
  <input type="submit" value="Filter!" />
</form>
```

with the following ajax call

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Report/Filter/",
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html"
        data: { filterOption: selectedFilterOption, filterOptionValue: selectedFilterValue },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#filterResultDiv').html(data);
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
```

which calls this controller method

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Filter(string filterOption, string filterOptionValue)
        {
            var filterCol = (FilterColumnName)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(FilterColumnName), filterOption);
            var singleFilter = new SingleFilter(filterCol, filterOptionValue);
            var entries = singleFilter.Filter();
            ...
            return PartialView("\\Places\\PartialReport", reportVM);
        }
```

and the error occurs while debugging this method

```
 public List<FilteredRow> Filter()
        {
            List<FilteredRow> result = new List<FilteredRow>();
            var ent = new Entities();

            var query = "SELECT * FROM V_Data WHERE " + this.GetFilterColumnName() + "= @p0";
            var dbObjects = ent.V_Data.SqlQuery(query, this.Value).ToList(); //<---- the ajax error function gets called after this line :(

            foreach (var obj in dbObjects)
            {
                var entry = new FilteredRow(obj);
                result.Add(entry);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

So after `var dbObjects = ent.V_Data.SqlQuery(query, this.Value).ToList();` the alert function gets called and shows "error: [object Object]"...but the Filter() method also returns the right amount of filtered entities to my controller method. The partial view shows up shortly and then the page gets reloaded. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this query works for all datatypes:

```
var valueParam = new SqlParameter("@p0", this.Value);
var dbObjects = ent.V_Data.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM V_Data WHERE " + this.GetFilterColumnName() + " = @p0", valueParam);
```

and in javascript i have to use

```
function Filter() {
      $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Filter")',
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                data: { filterOption: selectedFilterOption, filterOptionValue: selectedFilterValue },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#filterResultDiv').html(data);                
                },
                error: function (reponse) {
                    alert("error : " + reponse.toString());
                }
            });
            return false; //<- this avoids the page refresh!
          }
```